# How to integrate a newer release of python (2.7.18) into Anaconda Version 2019.10 with Python 2.7 (2.7.16)?

Tags: python, anaconda

It seems that Anaconda 2019.10 is the latest Version with python2 integrated in it.
This distribution has "python 2.7.16" integrated.
How can I integrate a newer release of python (2.7.18) into Anaconda Version 2019.10?

I have the installation for "python 2.7.18" (python-2.7.18.amd64.msi, around 20MB).
If I install this one also, what parts of the installed files would I have to copy to the Anaconda Destination path?

Comment: Tangential to the question at hand, but it’s important for you and other visitors to this question to note that Python 2.x has been [end-of-life](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) since 1 Jan 2020 and is not expected to receive any updates or security patches in the future.

Comment: Do you need the anaconda distribution? Perhaps you could move to the vanilla python 2.7.18 and install needed packages via pip.

Comment: @tdelaney; Thx for your question - I need the scientific packages that are all included in the Anaconda Version 2019.10 ...

Comment: They may also be available outside of anaconda.

Comment: The users that get this software don't have access to the Internet Source Files to install another package over pip ... - so I need a "one fits all" ... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it has been quite a while for this one, but better late than never ...

Someone from the administration team in the company has implemented a package server as a usable mirrored repository.
They are doing extensible security checks on new packages before sharing it on this package repository.

So, with a little "batch routine" for implementing this new environment our users are now able to implement new packages on their client machines, without even having administrative rights on their machines. :-)

For those of you who are interested in this little "batch routine", here it comes:

For configuration you first start an "Anaconda Prompt" and enter the following commands one after the other:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
conda config --set report_errors false
conda config --set channel_alias https://someserver.domainname.corp/repository
conda config --append channels py-anaconda/
conda config --append channels py-snapshots/
conda config --append channels py-releases/
conda config --append channels py-conda-forge/
conda config --append channels py-continuum/pkgs/main/
conda config --append channels py-continuum/pkgs/free/
conda config --append channels py-continuum/pkgs/r/
conda config --append channels py-continuum/pkgs/pro/
conda config --append channels py-continuum/pkgs/mro/
conda config --append channels py-continuum/pkgs/msys2/
conda config --append channels py-continuum/pkgs/mro-archive/
conda config --append channels py-continuum/pkgs/archive/
conda config --remove channels defaults
conda config --append repodata_fns repodata.json
conda config --append repodata_fns current_repodata.json
```

Of course you have to replace the "someserver.domainname.corp" with your own servername on your company ...

Since you do not have write permissions in the standard Anaconda environment, you must now create a new environment and activate it. To do this, enter the following commands ("name" stands for the name of the new environment):

```
conda create -n name
conda activate name
```

Now you can install new packages in this new environment using "conda install package name".

That's it - have fun :-)